# Apache2 reload and System Crash

Tags: kernel, server-crashes, ubuntu-11.04

Reloading Apache2 caused Ubuntu 11.04 to Hang/Crash.

```
 Load average was 32
```

**CPU Cores**:8

**Model**: Intel xeon E5620

**RAM**:16 GB

**Kernel** :2.6.38-13-generic

```
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.033031] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP 
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.054726] last sysfs file:   /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cache/index2/shared_cpu_map
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.097404] CPU 5 
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.097869] Modules linked in: nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ip6t_LOG xt_tcpudp ipt_REDIRECT xt_conntrack iptable_mangle nf_conntrack_ftp ipt_REJECT ipt_LOG xt_limit xt_multiport xt_state ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables vesafb snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec psmouse ioatdma snd_hwdep i7core_edac ghes edac_core lp hed dca joydev snd_pcm serio_raw parport snd_timer snd soundcore snd_page_alloc usbhid hid e1000e
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.279465] 
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.303429] Pid: 19118, comm: apache2 Not tainted 2.6.38-13-generic #56-Ubuntu Supermicro X8DTL/X8DTL
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.355544] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff81054cfa>]  [<ffffffff81054cfa>] task_rq_lock+0x4a/0xa0
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.411635] RSP: 0018:ffff88060b853da8  EFLAGS: 00010082
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.440241] RAX: 010021b86505c7ff RBX: 0000000000013d00 RCX: 00000001162d8937
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.497492] RDX: 0000000000000282 RSI: ffff88060b853df0 RDI: 00007fdac0088280
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.559362] RBP: ffff88060b853dc8 R08: 0000000000000040 R09: 001fc00000000000
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.625144] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: dead000000100100 R12: 00007fdac0088280
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.695569] R13: ffff88060b853df0 R14: 0000000000013d00 R15: 0000000000000005
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.770654] FS:  00007fdac0023760(0000) GS:ffff880c3fc20000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.849786] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.889882] CR2: 00007fdac187ca80 CR3: 000000058cda1000 CR4: 00000000000006e0
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715446.968627] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.049676] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.130842] Process apache2 (pid: 19118, threadinfo ffff88060b852000, task ffff88058c11c4a0)
 Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.212160] Stack:
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.251311]  00007fdac0088280 ffff880be1ca5ec8 000000000000000f 0000000000000000
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.331017]  ffff88060b853e28 ffffffff8105f2e1 0000000000000000 0000000081a4c270
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.412179]  ffff88060b853e38 0000000000000282 0000000000000021 ffff880b92505ec8
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.493302] Call Trace:
 Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.533014]  [<ffffffff8105f2e1>] try_to_wake_up+0x31/0x3e0
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.573262]  [<ffffffff8105f6c5>] wake_up_process+0x15/0x20
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.612669]  [<ffffffff8126b7c7>] wake_up_sem_queue_do+0x37/0x60
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.651327]  [<ffffffff8126c236>] freeary+0x1c6/0x200
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.689083]  [<ffffffff8126c32b>] semctl_down.clone.5+0xbb/0x110
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.726360]  [<ffffffff8107b6ae>] ? sys_kill+0x7e/0x90
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.762833]  [<ffffffff811663f5>] ? fput+0x25/0x30
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.798362]  [<ffffffff8126d05e>] sys_semctl+0x7e/0xd0
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.833126]  [<ffffffff8100c002>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.867350] Code: 00 48 c7 c3 00 3d 01 00 49 89 fc 49 89 f5 9c 58 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 89 c2 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 49 89 55 00 49 8b 44 24 08 49 89 de <8b> 40 18 4c 03 34 c5 80 c8 aa 81 4c 89 f7 e8 53 4e 57 00 49 8b 
 Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715447.970388] RIP  [<ffffffff81054cfa>] task_rq_lock+0x4a/0xa0
 Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715448.004042]  RSP <ffff88060b853da8>
 Apr 6 09:05:11 406852 kernel: [3715448.083219] ---[ end trace 244a1ec2d6f912fa ]---
```

**I understood these things from above logs,may not be correct:**

- Cause Related to Apache as it was showing Apache process id.
- Happened on CPU 5.
- Kernel is not Tainted
- Since General Protection Fault,hard reset was required to bring it back.

Can any one please help me in Analyzing this stack trace further more with reason.

Comment: Did you put an entry in .htaccess before you restarted? i was also facing the same issue. After editing .htaccess and do a restart the server get crash.Cpu load get increase too. What we did was we moved to a stable version of ubuntu.

Comment: yes exactly editing .htaccess and reloading crashed server,but apache restart didn't cause any crash.Do you have any idea about debugging stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a race in Linux kernel between `semtimedop()` timeout and `semctl(2)` with `IPC_RMID`:
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=27142

[Ubuntu Kernel git](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git) says that fix [was merged](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-natty.git;a=commit;h=e635bd0c141ce3ca04ff7ab4012899051e133285) in `Ubuntu-2.6.38-13.56-7-ge635bd0` on 5 Mar 2012.

Upgrading your kernel to (at least) `2.6.38-14-generic` (or moving to `LTS` release on your production servers) should fix your problem.